# Making a model for Nauto hand sign detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, fast-ai

I wanted to make a naruto hand sign detection model to later use it in a AR game and I tried implementing it in fastai using resnet50 after getting crowdsourcing the data( mostly me). But, I got a model predicting only one category for everything.

This is the kaggle link:

https://www.kaggle.com/vikranthkanumuru/naruto-hand-sign-detection-usin-fastai-diff-method

Not sure if this is a problem, but earlier I had around 28 images per group so I made a video of myself doing the various signs and used opencv to save frame by frame. I later removed the ones that did not confine to any group and this increased the size of the dataset from 220mb to 2GB. Was this proper or is it the reason the model is bad?

This is the link to the dataset

https://www.kaggle.com/vikranthkanumuru/naruto-hand-sign-dataset

I am not sure how to proceed further and would appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Edit: If anyone is interested in the completed thing, here's the link: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6640529067936440320/

Comment: I run your notebook and it's predicting multiple labels as expected??? See https://imgur.com/eJtyqej. What do you mean by "I got a model predicting only one category for everything"?

Comment: I tried taking each individual image from the test data and predicted on them. It gave me horse for everything. The code is at the bottom of the notebook for this. Did I maybe mess up something there?

Comment: I don't see the video in the input directory. Can you double check?

Comment: Yes, I added the video to this notebook but I don't have any code here in the above notebook in relation to a video. Are you perhaps checking out one of the other notebook I have made? Could you put a link on which one you are checking? Also, thank you very much for your help

Comment: OK I see what you mean now, let me check and see if I can find out why. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have fixed a bit of your code. Have a look. I did not run it for the whole stretch though but it should show you what you need.
- The test set only contained those images but take a look at the validation.
- Also switch to vgg16. resnet50 is not necessary here.
- https://www.kaggle.com/subhaditya/naruto-hand-sign-detection-using-fastai?scriptVersionId=29471636